# How to solve this gamma integral

Tags: integration, gamma-function, expectation

Let we have the (p.d.f) of x which is:

$$f(x)=\frac {\Gamma{(n-1)/2)}}{\Gamma{(1/2)} \Gamma{(n-2)/2)}}x(1-x^2)^{(n/2)-2}$$

then to find the $E(x) = $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x *(f(x) dx$ ; (Expectation of Mean)

Thus, we construct that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x) \frac{\Gamma{(n-1)/2)}}{\Gamma{(1/2)} \Gamma{(n-2)/2)}}(1-x^2)^{(n/2)-2}=??? $$

In my text book, it shows the result:

$$E(x) = 0 $$

Thanks

Comment: If you integrate between -1 and +1, you are not expected to have a result which should be a function of "r". Could you check if your post is correct ?

Comment: actually what i want to do is to find the $E(r)$ which is $E(r)$= $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} r (p.d.f (r))$. Then $(p.d.f (r))$ is  $\frac{\Gamma{(n-1)/2)}}{\Gamma{(1/2)} \Gamma{(n-2)/2)}}r(1-r^2)^{(n/2)-2}dr~~;(-1\leq r\leq 1)$

Comment: Sorry but is the equation wrong in the post ?

Comment: Either we speak about the integral and the result does not depend on "r" either we speak about the antiderivative and the result depends on "r" (but in this case no bounds on the integral), either your text book is stupid ! Please, try to clarify. I shall do my best to help.

Comment: Forget about the constants. Decompose your integral in the two aprts I suggested. They cancel each other. Then, zero is the result. The antiderivative is (1 - r^2)^(n/2 - 1) / (2 -n).

Comment: Hi claude thanks for the comment, any way can u provide the latex for that? so I would be more confidence with the answer..thanks Claude

Comment: Sorry for not using LaTex. I am almost blind and I don't "see" what I am typing. Apologies. By, the way, if my answers have been useful, you can accept them.

Comment: ohh i see, any way i can not reach the answer that u give to me, please can u provide the full of antiderivative proceess claude? i do not find similar like your answer $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (r)(1-r^2)^{(n/2)-2}=??? $$

Comment: Please, compute the derivative of (1-r^2)^(n/2 -1) / (2-n) and check. Change variable to make life easier : 1 - r^2 = y^2 and you just need to integrate -y^(n-3) dy. Is that better ? Cheers.

Comment: Unbalanced parentheses: never a good sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**Whatever is your problem, did you notice that the derivative of (1 - r^2) looks like r ? On the other hand, what does happen is you split your integral (from -1 to 0 and from 0 to 1) ? Can you continue with this ?